# Funciona en NetBeans pero NO funciona el JAR

Tags: java, netbeans, jar

Hola que tal buenas a todos. 
Necesito ayuda.
Estoy realizando un proyecto que consta basicamente en realizar un chat que se comunica leyendo archivos, solo puede comunicarse ejecutando varias veces el mismo jar. 
Consiste basicamente en permitir al usuario elegir un tipo de chat, un nombre para el chat y una ruta para guardarlo. Luego se muestra al usuario una caja de texto y un boton de guardar, entonces el usuario escribe algo y presiona el boton enviar; Hay 3 tipos de chat, el normal (que no encripta la informacion), el tipo encriptado(que manipula el codigo ascii de cada letar) y el tipo privado (que juega con la posicion de las letras para encriptar la informacion)

En el IDE NETBEANS funcionan los 3 tipos de chats perfectamente. Pero al ejecutar el jar, el chat Encriptado no funciona bien.

Basicamente el tipo de cha encriptado, toma cada letra y la convierte a su valor respectivo de caracter (codigo ascii) y le resta 15. de esta manera por ejemplo si se ingresa la letra a, entonces su codigo ascii es 97, entonces le agrega 15 y su nuevo codigo entonces es 112, y convierte ese numero a un char y luego a un string, por lo que la letra nueva seria "p", y asi sucecivamente para las demas letras, quedando entonces la informacion encriptada. Tambien el programa es capaz de abrir nuevamente el archivo y leer e interpretar la informacion( es decir desencriptar la informacion y mostrarla)

Al ejecutar el programa en NetBeans todo va de maravilla.
el problema es cuando ejecuto el archivo JAR que me genera el IDE, entonces solo convierte correctamente las letras desde la "a" hasta la letra "p", y desde la letra q hasta la z no lo hace correctamente. Que esta sucediendo??? Acaso no deberia funcionar de igual manera???

NOTA: si sirve de algo, al generar el archivo JAR me aparece esto: 
Note: C:\Users--SuperMarioBross!--\Documents\NetBeansProjects\Practica4\src\Chat.java uses or overrides a deprecated API.

Note: Recompile with -Xlint:deprecation for details.

Este es el jar generado:
https://mega.nz/#!fI1hHD4R!uFWfwdDIGQJi1m3-Q3WlZq7arL4duzZdFZImbPP8SG4

Comment: ¿Y el código? ¿Podrías subir a algún lugar el .jar generado? ¿Podrías decirle a tu IDE que incluya tanto las clases como el código java? Es probable que el JAR no esté actualizándose con el nuevo código y esté en él alguna versión antigua. Pero sin código ni JAR no somos adivinos para saber qué te está ocurriendo. ¿Podrías explicar correctamente la conversión que hace de texto para ver si podemos deducir si es algún tipo de problema de cadenas unicode/iso-8859-x?

Comment: Bueno la verdad es que por simpleza dije que era un escritor de archivos, pero en realidad es un chat que funciona escribiendo archivos. Ya he subido el jar generado.

Comment: Creo que estás usando el .jar que no es. ¿De qué carpeta lo estás sacando? Si es un proyecto no maven, usualmente NetBeans lo guarda en  la carpeta `/dist/` de tu proyecto. Si es maven, lo encontrarás en la carpeta `target` del proyecto, es el archivo que tiene el nombre de tu jar, la versión y al final la palabra `SNAPSHOOT.jar`. Eso es si tienes la configuración por defecto. Ah, y para más seguridad corre la opción `Run/Clean and Build`

Comment: Empieza a molestarme el que se vote negativo en las preguntas sin comentar el por qué del voto negativo. Ya llevo varias respuestas aceptadas votadas negativo, y algunas preguntas. Es algo realmente molesto.

Comment: Estoy contigo @A.Cedano, es molesto y no hace justicia al autor de la pregunta. Y estoy también contigo en que tiene pinta de que no está usando el JAR adecuado. @Abner, ¿has comprobado la fecha de última modificación de ese JAR? ¿Has generado el JAR con todo lo que te dije para poder ver su contenido? Ya que sólo tú conoces cuál es el código fuente "bueno" sólo tú podrás abrir el JAR (con cualquier aplicación como winzip, winrar, 7zip, etc) y comparar el `.java` y repetir la prueba de funcionamiento.

Comment: Gracias por su ayuda A.Cedano y  OscarGarcia, he eliminado el archivo jar, y lo he vuelto a crear, y nada :(

Comment: Con respecto a si es un proyecto maven o no maven, no estoy muy seguro de lo que significa eso. Pero si sirve de algo, estoy generando la funcion grafica del IDE (el drag and drop)

Comment: Si corre bien en NetBeans no hay motivo para que el jar generado falle, a no ser que no estés generando ninguno. Puedes hacer una búsqueda en el directorio de tu proyecto poniendo `.jar` y ahí debe estar tu jar, generado hace algunos minutos. Si no está y si no tiene fecha muy reciente, entonces no lo está generando. Imagino que estás corriendo el proyecto usando la opción `Run` del menú superior y luego seleccionando `Clean and Build`. Normalmente en el output de abajo te dice al final la ubicación del jar.

Comment: efectivamente si esta generando el archivo jar, tiene fecha y hora de justo cuando selecciono clean and build. pero sigue sin funcionar correctamente:(